# Share Buttons Will Not Show

Tags: php, html, wordpress, share, share-button

I've created a custom blog page to go along with my WordPress website.  This page is made to show only 1 category form the blog feed.  I've added the "AddThis" plugin share buttons and manually coded it in the theme.

The problem is the buttons will not show.  I've attempted other share plugins into the page but they will not show either.  Now, the buttons do work as they show up on other blog pages and the articles themselves.

Here is the website of the page and the code, am I missing something or do I need to change a line of code?

[Page with non-working share buttons](http://www.easycarebaths.com/online-reviews/)

[Page with working share buttons](http://www.easycarebaths.com/mr-mrs-langton-newport-mi/)

```
<?php /* Template Name: Page - Online Reviews */ ?>
```

```
    <div class="main_container">
        <div class="page_container">


    <h2 style="border-bottom: solid thin #000; line-height: 50px; margin-bottom: 50px;"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <?php
    $temp = $wp_query;
    $wp_query = NULL;
    $wp_query = new WP_Query();
    $wp_query->query('cat=4&paged='.$paged); $tb_counter = 1;
    while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
    <div <?php if(function_exists('post_class')) : ?><?php post_class(); ?><?php else : ?>class="post post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"<?php endif; ?>>
        <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php printf(__('Permanent Link to %s','easycarebath'),the_title_attribute('echo=0')); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( sprintf( __( '%s', 'easycarebath' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
            <!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
            <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style ">
                <a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="button_count"></a>
                <a class="addthis_button_tweet"></a>
                <a class="addthis_button_google_plusone" g:plusone:size="medium"></a>
                <a class="addthis_button_linkedin_counter"></a>
                <a class="addthis_counter addthis_pill_style"></a>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">var addthis_config = {"data_track_addressbar":true};</script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-4dd51ec729a7fec7"></script>
            <!-- AddThis Button END -->
    <footer class="entry-meta">
    <?php the_time(__('M d, Y', 'easycarebath')); ?> | <?php _e('Categories:','easycarebath'); if (the_category(', '))  the_category(); ?> <?php if (get_the_tags()) the_tags(__('| Tags: ','easycarebath')); ?> | <?php comments_popup_link(__('Leave A Comment »', 'easycarebath'), __('1 Comment »', 'easycarebath'),__ngettext('% Comment »', '% Comments »',get_comments_number (),'easycarebath')); ?> <?php edit_post_link(__('Edit','easycarebath'), '| ', ''); ?>
    </footer>
    <?php $tb_counter++; endwhile; ?>
    <nav id="nav-below" class="navigation" role="navigation">
        <div class="nav-previous alignright"><?php next_posts_link(__('&laquo; Older Entries','easycarebath')); ?></div>
        <div class="nav-next alignleft"><?php previous_posts_link(__('Newer Entries &raquo;','easycarebath')); ?></div>
    </nav>
    <?php $wp_query = NULL; $wp_query = $temp;?>

        </div>
        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: Looks like you are missing `get_footer()`...

Comment: I do have both 'get_footer()' and 'get_header()' in the code so it wouldn't be that.

Comment: All the content that should be within the `<head>` tag seems to be within the `<body>` tag. Have you put `wp_head()` in the right place?

Comment: Yes, I have the `wp_head();` right before the `</head>`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.  It's not the code that was the issue, it was Transmit that was not saving the code properly.  After a restart of the program, I was able to save the code and the share buttons were able to show up.

Thanks everyone for your attempt, it was a software problem. :)